# Module Programming Framework for ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, module, content-management-system

my boss says to me

"I want a web portal that allows me to install/uninstall new modules. These modules, when installed, can be dragged as widgets onto a portal dashboard and if u navigate to a widget, it will contain its own set of pages. I also want an admin portal where I can set the security level on each module. Lastly modules should be distributable separately from the portal. And yeah, I'm not paying for SharePoint".

I first got excited because I immediately saw in my mind  how I would build this. Then I thought, wait, this isn't a new problem, don't CMSs do this? My question is have you guys come across any open source ASP.NET MVC frameworks that I can build upon that already provide this sort of module programming? Or maybe a "light-weight CMS" (a CMS may be overkill for what I want) that I can build on?

Comment: Not open source, but Telerik's Sitefinity does an amazing job of all of that, and is *very* customizable. You can even use the admin interface to edit the admin interface.